# Force EF Core 2.0 migration to use full name space of the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to generate the migration script using the below command

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitApplicationDbContext -c ApplicationDbContext -o Migrations/ApplicationDbContext
```

It successfully generates the script, but when I try to build the project it shows the error

> 'ApplicationDbContext is a namespace but used like a type'

The generated file looks like the following

```
namespace Service.Migrations.ApplicationDbContext
{
    [DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
    [Migration("20180424060822_InitApplicationDbContext")]
    partial class InitApplicationDbContext
    {
        protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
          // Removed for clarity
        }
    }
}
```

The error is on this line `[DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]`. 
If I change this line to include the namespace where the context is declared then all works fine `[DbContext(typeof(Service.Context.ApplicationDbContext))]`
Another options is to remove the context name from the namespace in the auto generated code, like `namespace Service.Migrations.ApplicationDbContext` to `namespace Service.Migrations`

Is there a way to force the dotnet ef command to specify the namespace or use the full type name of the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can't specify namespace by yourself, but they have that issue in [backlog](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9723) so you can expect to have it in future releases.

Comment: Thank you for the related issue link. I am currently going with some workaround to avoid the manual changes inside the auto generated code by specifying a different name of the output folder in the command line. Hopefully it will be fixed in the future version.